# Unable to enter recovery mode & download mode

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset, boot-loop

I was formatting my *Alcatel OT 918N* from recovery mode. After deleting cache partition and wiping data from recovery mode I restarted my phone but then it went in an infinite boot loop i.e. it starts but right before displaying the home screen it restarts again.

Now I am not able to go in recovery mode too. When I try to go in recovery mode, my phone freezes on android logo. I have tried almost every key combination but my phone doesn't enters download mode, the only mode which comes is factory mode in which there are device testing options.

My device was running on stock ROM but it was rooted.

Please help me out.

Comment: http://www.makeuseof.com/answers/why-wont-my-alcatel-918a-phone-boot/

Comment: @Enigma Maybe you make that a full-fledged answer, including the essential parts behind the link and having the link itself as reference?

Comment: @Izzy: It's really just a small conglomeration of information that I can't personally validate. If the OP could attest to a particular bit of information on that page being useful then I would count that as a potential answer.

Comment: @Enigma good point (+1), I couldn't know that (link-only comment ;). So let's hope Amit returns to give some feedback on this!

Comment: @Enigma your link was really very helpful, in it there is a link for [XDA Developer thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1972704) which is really good for `unbricking` or installing `stock ROM` on *Alcatel OT 918* but I didn't needed that much steps. I just used the `Alcatel OT-918 Upgrade Tool` to upgrade my ROM and it started to work perfectly. Thanks for help :)